# get windows edition in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2010

Hia all
Is there any method using VB.NET API to detect Win Edition (e.g. Home/Professional/...)

I tried the sample i found here [How can I determine the Windows version from a VB 6 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839210/how-can-i-determine-the-windows-version-from-a-vb-6-app), but **`osv.OSVSize = Len(osv)`** gets me an error in VB2010Espress: Variable 'osv' is used before it has been assigned a value...

PS I don't want to use WMI

Comment: VB6 works nothing at all like VB.net. That example won't be of any use to you.

Comment: i am using Environment.OSVersion to get the major and minor version, but i don't know hot to get the edition

Comment: This looks promising, but I've never looked into the issue myself. Good luck. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304289

Answer (score 1):

The following is not at all bullet proof (as the string returned may vary according to the culture and may change without warning in a new version of windows) but it may be good enough for what you want:

```
    If My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.ToUpper.Contains("PROFESSIONAL") Then
        Debug.WriteLine("Proffessional")
    ElseIf My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.ToUpper.Contains("HOME") Then
        Debug.WriteLine("Home")
    elseif ...
        'etc
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found GetProductInfo into Kernel32.dll, looking into it....